# How android ROMS based on TouchWiz work if TouchWiz source code is not available as opensource?

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-touchwiz, open-source

Source code of samsung-touchwiz is not available to public to download and use. But there are custom roms which have touchwiz UI available .How do touch-wiz based roms like Salman rom work  without having samsung touch-wiz code?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung allegedly releases the kernel sources, allowing a developer to customize and compile a kernel. Since they can also download the binary ROM (or copy it from their device), they can use their kernel as a drop-in replacement in the TouchWiz ROM--providing their changes didn't break the communication with the drivers. They normally don't touch the drivers or the userland apps, just the kernel.

Alternatively a user can tweak the default ROM by adding apps and/or themes ('kitchen work'). This has little real value to consumers and is not considered *original* development.

Answer (score 0):

In the days I used to play with ROMs, there used to be some system folder (I think `system/app`) that contains .apk files (installer files). You'd need root and access to these folders to replace a non-working Market/vending/Play or Camera application, or TouchWiz (if memory didn't fail me).

So, I think it's just a matter of copying the .apk and including it in the system folder.